# How to center-align Bootstrap Images when decreasing browser window (responsive)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my code sample. in `full-width` of the browser everything looks fine. But when I resize it, the images (cards) are more towards the left side (not centered).
How can I fix this?

HTML code:

```
<div  class="container-fluid">          
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>              
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Since I'm using `Bootstrap v4`, it should automatically adjust according to the page. But here is what I experience...

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtOmO.jpg)

Comment: Seems to be working as intended. Each column gets set to 100% width when you pass the `md` breakpoint.

Comment: Yes, but did you see the image I have attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `display: inline-block;` to the `img` tag then apply `text-align: center;` to the parent;

In your code, you have applied `display: block;` to the image tag. Where now image act as a blocked element. That's why your image is not aligned in the center.

I have applied `text-align: center;` for `imghvr-fold-up`, because I can handle the caption and images in a single point.

**Output:**

```css
//CSS
.img-thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
            <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                <figcaption class="">
                    Hello
                </figcaption>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <figure class="imghvr-fold-up text-center">
                <figcaption class="">
                    Hello
                </figcaption>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <figure class="imghvr-fold-up text-center">
                <figcaption>
                    Hello
                </figcaption>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <figure class="imghvr-fold-up text-center">
                <figcaption>
                    Hello
                </figcaption>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <figure class="imghvr-fold-up text-center">
                <figcaption>
                    Hello
                </figcaption>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <figure class="imghvr-fold-up text-center">
                <figcaption>
                    Hello
                </figcaption>
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo at [codepen.](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/mBpOMW)

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: Checkout my demo in codepen. Did you applied the "text-center" class  in the "imghvr-fold-up".

Comment: No..... i haven't

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a spacer class on the image when on smaller screens `mx-sm-auto`, for more info on these see here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Not working.........

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:auto` and `display: block` to image to center it

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfj260ry/)

```css
.img-thumbnail{margin:auto;display:block}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div  class="container-fluid">          
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>              
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <figure class="imghvr-fold-up">
                    <figcaption class="text-center">
                        Hello                           
                    </figcaption>                        
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre">
                </figure>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is `.img-thumbnail` ??? I haven't use anything like that...

Comment: But i can see in your html code `class="img-thumbnail" which is`added to `img`

Comment: add `.img-thumbnail{margin:auto;display:block}` this class to your css

Comment: No, it's not working. Still it's the same

Comment: check my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rfj260ry/ are you resizing? i think your css is not properly linking to html

Comment: No it's properly linked Sir. and when I add a different style, it works. but nor yours. I even tries using `!important`

Comment: I have done the what you have told... not working... In my case the css is not working on `img-thumbnail` and I don't know why...

Comment: can you  add your code in the new fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes I done it and it is still the same. Shit!

Comment: Here `https://jsfiddle.net/z3bLncpg/`

Comment: check this one https://jsfiddle.net/z3bLncpg/2/

Comment: Have you checked the updated fiddle?

Comment: Yes Sir. Now it's working. But One problem. in here, every image resides vertically by keeping only one image horizontally. `Can I first keep 3 images horizontally as a row when i resize and then 2 images horizontally, then finally at further resizing only one image horizontally as you have done now?`